# Having pointers inside struct fields?

Tags: go, pointers

If I need access to an int on a struct then I can use a pointer receiver, but I can also use a receiver with a pointer add to the struct field i.e.

```
type Something struct {
    counter  *int
    counter1 int
}
```

So the above counter, is actually a pointer so I can get access to it and update it from a receiver.

Of course this other way is to leave it as a non pointer and use a pointer recevier.

As far as I ma aware, the reasons for placing pointers into fields of a struct is to ensure you don't get a default value - in case of an int, the int would get 0 as a default value but maybe you want to present that it is missing.

But adding a pointer to a struct just so you don't need to use a pointer receiver would cause problems or is recommended ?

Considering the pattern in go is if 1 receiver is a pointer receiver then all receviers should be  pointer receivers

Thanks in advance

I have proved that both a pointer receiver and just a pointer on a struct with a receiver, gives the same results.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues within this question:

In general, if you want to change the values in a struct, you have to use a pointer receiver. It is correct that if the struct has pointer values you can modify the value they are pointing to, but you still cannot modify where it points.

The reason for putting pointers varies from situation to situation, and preventing a default value is just one of them.

The following statement is wrong:

"Considering the pattern in go is if 1 receiver is a pointer receiver then all receviers should be pointer receivers"

Methods defined with pointer receivers are only defined for addressable instances of the type. Methods defined with value receivers are defined for both pointer and value instances of a type. You can define methods with both pointer and value receivers.

In general, if a method modifies the values of a struct, that method must use a pointer receiver.

So, in short, how you use pointer fields in a struct depends on the situation. There is no general rule or pattern you need to follow.